# How to add a character in a string by checking the delimiter?

Tags: c, string

I have a string in my program where in which it need to be altered with another string value before a "/".

Source String : qos-tree/output_rate
Target String : qos-tree-2/output_rate

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char* s, char c)
{
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
        char str[256] = "qos-tree/output_rate";
        char c = "a";

        append(str, c);

        printf("%s\n", str);
        return 0;
}
```

This is what i have done so far,I think the logic is wrong here.Can anyone guide me to correct it?
Once the execution is completed the source string should have a "-2" before the "/"

Comment: Nothing in your "logic" inserts "-2". Also, nothing in your logic looks for a slash. Consider trying fixing both first.

Comment: If you want to do it in-place, find the /, memmove everything after 2 chars to the right and add your "-2". Protip: Start by finding the '/'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void insert_before_ch(char *s, const char *ins, char c){
    char *p = strchr(s, c);
    if(p){
        size_t len = strlen(ins);
        memmove(p + len, p, strlen(p)+1);
        memcpy(p, ins, len);
    }
}

int main(void){
    char str[256] = "qos-tree/output_rate";

    insert_before_ch(str, "-2", '/');

    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your attempt, you don't look for a slash and I do not see any "-2" anywhere.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void append(char* s, char del, char* substring) {
  char origin[256];
  strcpy(origin, s);
  int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0;

  for(; origin[i]; ++i) {
    if(origin[i] != del) {
      s[j++] = origin[i];
    } else {
      for(; substring[z]; ++z) {
        s[j++] = substring[z];
      }
      s[j++] = origin[i];
    }
  }
  s[j] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
  char str[256] = "qos-tree/output_rate";
  char del = '/';
  char* substring = "-2";

  append(str, del, substring);

  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

The logic is that inside the function we use `origin` array to remember the actual contents of the array and then we copy from `origin` to `s` (which is the actual array of `main()`). If we find our delimiter `del`, then we copy the `substring` in that position and continuing with copying.

---

Note that the length of the array should be enough to store the resulted string. In this case, it is.

Comment: **Note**: this code will not work if the array is not long enough.

Comment: Of course @iharob. Good point though for beginners, I should put it as an edit. Thanks, nice answer by the way, +1.

Answer (score 1):

first of all thist `char c = "a"` should be replace with this `char c = 'a';` because `c` is a character not a string

as for your problem I didn't realy see the relation between what your code is doing with what you said you wanted to do , but here a piece of code to achieve what , I think , you want to do :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




void append(char* str , char c)
{
    char firststr[60];
    char therest[30];
    strcpy(firststr , strtok(str , "/"));
    strcpy(therest , strtok(NULL , "/"));
    strcat(firststr , &c);
    strcat(firststr , "/");
    strcat(firststr , therest);
    strcpy(str , firststr);
}
int main(void)
{
    char str[60] = "qos-tree/output_rate";
    char c = '2';

    append(str , c);
    printf("%s\n" , str);
}
```

there you go I think this is what you wanted to do you can modify the array sizes to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your function work with dynamic allocation, because inserting characters into the string will make the resulting string larger, so this is my suggestion

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert(char **str, char chr, unsigned int position)
{
        int   length;
        char *ptr;

        if (str == NULL)
                return;
        length = strlen(*str);
        if (position >= length)
                return;
        ptr = realloc(*str, 2 + length);
        if (ptr == NULL)
                return;
        *str = ptr;

        memmove(ptr + position + 1, ptr + position, length - position + 1);
        ptr[position] = chr;
}

int main(void)
{
        const char *source = "qos-tree/output_rate";
        size_t      length = strlen(source);
        char       *str    = malloc(1 + length);

        if (str == NULL)
                return -1;
        strcpy(str, source);

        insert(&str, '-', 8);
        insert(&str, '2', 9);

        printf("%s\n", str);

        free(str);
        return 0;
}
```